# Apache mod_rewrite or other mod to reorder GET parameters in every link to right order? (for SEO)

Tags: django, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have many different links to one page at my site.

Something like
ukrhimplast.com/products/product/?type=tanks&product_category=plastic_tanks&product_type=vertical_tanks&product=v_505
and
ukrhimplast.com/products/product/?type=tanks&product_type=vertical_tanks&product=v_505&product_category=plastic_tanks
and
ukrhimplast.com/products/product/?product_category=plastic_tanks&type=tanks&product_type=vertical_tanks&product=v_505

Google thinks that this is different pages, because on query "V-505 tank" it gives 3 results with links mentioned above, that leads at the same page.

I need apache to redirect all this pages to one with right parameters order like
1 - type, 2 - product_category, 3 - product_type, 4 - product
ukrhimplast.com/products/product/?type=tanks&product_category=plastic_tanks&product_type=vertical_tanks&product=v_505

How can I achieve this result? I use apache and django. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your concern is Google counting these all as separate pages, a better solution is to [use a  tag](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en) on those pages.  So in the template for your products page, put something like:

```
<head>
...
<link rel="canonical" href="{% url 'products' %}?type={{type}}&product_category={{product_category}}&product_type={{product_type}}&product={{product_id}}
</head>
```

Comment: As I now, this is not really right way, because "canonical" doesn't mean "the same page". It means "page with same information, but with other representation or view".  
Am I right?

Comment: It's used in both cases. It tells google "all URLs with a given canonical link should count as the page, and should use this as the URL that appears in search results." This is a better approach than setting a bunch of 301 redirects in django or your web server (your web server shouldn't need to know that much info about your app)